# Python 3.2 Unable to import urllib2 (ImportError: No module named urllib2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, urllib2

I am using Windows, and I get the error:

```py
ImportError: No module named urllib2
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532321/python-importerror-no-module-named-urllib) is the solution for Linux. But how to set this in Windows?

I am using Python 3.2 and I am not able see `urllib2` there in the LiB folder.

Comment: urllib2 is merged into urllib in python3.see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package

Comment: @newbie you can put this comment into an answer

Comment: newbie's answer should be accepted.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate since its about urllib2 and the duplicate is about urllib. Answers to both questions are distinctly useful.

Answer (score 147):

In python 3 urllib2 was merged into urllib. *See also [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib) and the [urllib PEP 3108](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package).*

To make Python 2 code work in Python 3:

```
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
```

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain how to solve the problem? From the link I see that some changes were made in the package, but what with should I replace `urllib2` in the the python command to succeed installation? Replacing `urllib2` with `urllib.request` doesn't help.

Comment: Note that you also need to add decode() to your line reader, ie change from row = line.strip().split(",") to row = line.decode().strip().split(",")

Answer (score 24):

PYTHON 3

```
import urllib.request

wp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://example.com")

pw = wp.read()

print(pw)
```

PYTHON 2

```
import urllib

 import sys

 wp = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com")

 for line in wp:

     sys.stdout.write(line)
```

While I have tested both the Codes in respective versions.

Answer (score 5):

```
    import urllib2
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

```
    import urllib2
```

ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'
So urllib2 has been been replaced by  the package : urllib.request.

Here is the PEP  link (Python Enhancement Proposals )

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package

so instead of urllib2 you can now import  urllib.request and then use it  like this:

```
    >>>import urllib.request

    >>>urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.placementyogi.com')
```

Original Link : http://placementyogi.com/articles/python/importerror-no-module-named-urllib2-in-python-3-x