# Using urllib2 to fetch internet resources in 3.3.2

Tags: api, python-3.x, python-module

I am trying to learn to build API's in Python. I want to start with something simple, just fetching simple internet resources. After reading different sources, it appears i'll need to import urlllib2 module but there is no such module in the installation. Is there somewhere to dl or at least get a list of modules in a Python installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3.2 Unable to import urllib2 (ImportError: No module named urllib2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594620/python-3-2-unable-to-import-urllib2-importerror-no-module-named-urllib2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urllib2` module has been integrated into the `urllib` module in Python3.

Here is the pep link that describes the change - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package

Simply use `urllib` instead. It's been greatly improved.