# Syntax Issue in Python urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

Am trying to test out urllib2.  Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
print response.info()
html = response.read()
response.close()
```

When I run it, I get:

Syntax Error: invalid syntax.  Carrot points to line 3 (the print line).  Any idea what's going on here?  I'm just trying to follow a tutorial and this is the first thing they do...

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Just so you know, in most practical situations you will be better off using the `requests` library instead of the `urllib` module.  That isn't related to the specific issues you're having here, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3 [`print` is a *function*](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). Therefore it needs parentheses around its argument:

```
print(response.info())
```

In Python2, `print` is a *statement*, and hence does not require parentheses.

---

After correcting the SyntaxError, as alecxe points out, you'll probably encounter an ImportError next. That is because the Python2 module called `urllib2` was renamed to [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) in Python3. So you'll need to change it to

```
import urllib.request as request
response = request.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
```

---

As you can see, the tutorial you are reading is meant for Python2. You might want to find a [Python3 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or [Python3 urllib HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html) to avoid running into more of these problems.

Comment: Then, why doesn't it throw an error on the `import` line?

Comment: @alecxe: SyntaxErrors occur before ImportErrors. But you are right, that is probably the next problem to occur.

Comment: @alecxe yeah so now I get that import error :) I tried adding parentheses but it says it ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'...ideas?

Comment: @unutbu I think `print` is still a statement in python2. (Unless you import the print function from the future).

Comment: @Mariogs there is no more `urllib2` in python 3: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594620/python-3-2-unable-to-import-urllib2-importerror-no-module-named-urllib2

Comment: @Mariogs Because you are doing a python2 tutorial in python3... that's why.