# Reading this type of Json with Python 3 Urllib

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

My json url has this:

```
{years=["2014","2015","2016"]}
```

How can I get this strings from URL with Python 3? I know this method but Python 3 has no urllib2 module.

```
import urllib2
import json
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1/years.php')
data = json.load(response)   
print (data)
```

*ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'*

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' :(

Comment: urllib2 no longer exists in Python 3.

Comment: From the Python 3 documentation for [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib2): "urllib.request.urlopen() corresponds to the old urllib2.urlopen".

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the import to `urllib`, and use `urllib.request` instead. For the reason being, please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594620/python-3-2-unable-to-import-urllib2-importerror-no-module-named-urllib2)

```
import urllib
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1/years.php')
data = json.load(response)   
print (data)
```