# Spyder Anaconda cannot launch

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have windows 10 and i downloaded the latest version of Anaconda. After installing, i opened Anaconda prompt and i tried to open spyder with command *start spyder* but it didn't open. 
The error message on pop-up is: Spyder crashed during last session.

The error message in command is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\github.py", line 51, in 
    from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPSHandler, Request, HTTPError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'.

I tried to solve the problem with spyder --reset, but it didn't fix.
 What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with these tools, but it looks like a Python 2 vs Python 3 issue to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594620/python-3-2-unable-to-import-urllib2-importerror-no-module-named-urllib2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html You may need to make sure you have the correct dependencies installed.

Comment: @MitchLindgren I think this is a good insight, but the version of Spyder (v3.3.6) that ships with latest Anaconda [has a try...except pattern](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/v3.3.6/spyder/utils/external/github.py#L51) to handle both 2 and 3, so I don't see why this exception would bubble up here.