# Creating an executable from python script

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to create a standalone executable file from python script using py2exe (following instructions at [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) ). When I run the setup.py from cmd, it shows an error saying "no module named urllib", although urllib is a builtin module. Please help out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532321/python-importerror-no-module-named-urllibDo you get the error when you run the script too>
See if this helps.

Comment: I was scanning the web and found [this](http://www.logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script)

Comment: I found pyinstaller to be much easier to use. Without specifying anything it includes all dependencies.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: No it works perfectly in eclipse

Comment: Can you check if you are able to import urllib from a cmd window.

Comment: How do you do that? (Sorry, i'm a newbie)